# Decorator pattern - access value in wrapped object from decorator

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I have a question about the decorator pattern

Lets say I have this code

```
interface IThingy 
{
    void Execute(); 
}

internal class Thing : IThingy
{
    public readonly string CanSeeThisValue;

    public Thing(string canSeeThisValue)
    {
        CanSeeThisValue = canSeeThisValue;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    } 
}

class Aaa : IThingy 
{
    private readonly IThingy thingy;

    public Aaa(IThingy thingy)
    {
        this.thingy = thingy;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    } 
}


class Bbb : IThingy {
    private readonly IThingy thingy;

    public Bbb(IThingy thingy)
    {
        this.thingy = thingy;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    } 
}

class Runit {
    void Main()
    {
        Aaa a = new Aaa(new Bbb(new Thing("Can this be accessed in decorators?")));
    } 
}
```

We have a class called thing that is wrapped by two decorators Aaa and Bbb

How can I best access the string value "CanSeeThisValue" (which is in Thing) from Aaa or Bbb

I tried to make a base class for them all, but of course while they share the same base, they don't share the same instance of the base

Do I need to pass the value into each constructor instead?

Comment: Decorators enhance the functionality using the public interface of whatever they are wrapping, they should have knowledge of anything beyond that, typically.

Comment: Can you make that field static in the base class? Or add a new property to IThingy? That way the decorated classes can be used in a loop to retrieve the value of that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators add functionality to the public interface of the items they are wrapping.  If you want your decorator to access members of `Thing`, that are not part of `IThingy`, then you should consider whether the decorator should wrap `Thing` instead of `IThingy`.

Or, if all `IThingy` should have a `CanSeeThisValue` property, make that property part of the `IThingy` interface as well by adding (and implementing) it as a property.

```
interface IThingy 
{
    string CanSeeThisValue { get; }

    void Execute(); 
}
```

Which would make `Thing` look like:

```
internal class Thing : IThingy
{
    public string CanSeeThisValue { get; private set; }

    public Thing(string canSeeThisValue)
    {
        CanSeeThisValue = canSeeThisValue;
    }

    ...

}
```